# Get a geosjon band based on a random point and a random angle

Tags: d3.js, maps, geojson

I'm trying to do some kind of [rubber band ball](http://d33y93cfm0wb4z.cloudfront.net/Lana/OMO/Activity_images/iStock_000015291546XSmall_228x140.jpg) in d3, I thought it was going to be easy because I remember seeing [Jason Davies example](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/clip/) (the 2nd one at the top) but it looks like it was more complex actually.

Jason's example for a vertical band is quite straightfoward:

```
let band = [2, -2].map((d, i) => {
    let stripe = d3.range(-180, 180).map((x) => [x, d])
    stripe.push(stripe[0])
    return i ? stripe.reverse() : stripe
})
```

So I starting by making a vertical band like this:

```
let band = [2, -2].map((d, i) => {
    let stripe = d3.range(-90, 90).map((y) => [d, y])
    stripe.push(stripe[0])
    return i ? stripe.reverse() : stripe
})
```

But instead, I get this weird shape that closes on each pole (it's supposed to be filled too, not stroked):

[image: globe]

My end goal would be to simply specify a point, an angle and a width (4 in my example) and it would return the coordinates necessary to draw a band around the globe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a fairly simple problem because of d3.
I used `d3.geo.circle` with an angle of 90° (default) and a random point, so:

```
let circle = d3.geo.circle()
    .origin(coords)()
```

Since `d3.geo.circle` returns a polygon, I needed to edit it's properties:

```
circle.type = 'LineString'
circle.coordinates = circle.coordinates[0]
```

Here's the final result:

[image: globes]